# Using regular expression to strip out every character that's not in a list

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I want to strip out every character that isn't in a list of valid characters.

In this example, I want to strip out everything that's either: (a) not alphanumeric, or (b) is the e accent grave character:

```
Line = rereplace(Line,'[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789' + Chr(233) + ']','','all')
```

I think , I just need a '**not**' symbol or something .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use shortcuts for most of that:

```
Line = rereplace(Line,'[^A-Za-z0-9' + Chr(233) + ']','','all')
```

The `^` inside the bracket means 'not these characters'

Comment: Oh, ok.  I was reading [If the caret is at the beginning of a regular expression, the matched string must be at the beginning of the string being searched](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html).

Comment: That is true, but when inside square brackets it behaves as a NOT.

Comment: I've updated the docs to mention `^` in the context of a character set: https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Regular+expression+syntax